# How to make a run configuration in eclipse using CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, debian, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to compile a code i made in C in Debian using CDT for Eclipse and i'm having the famouse **Binary not found** error when i try to compile the code. I already build the code by pressing `Ctrl+B` and the Debug folder appears, and the code doesn't have any syntax error, but the error still there. After that i tried to make a run configuration for my project but i'm not sure about what to put where it say's `C/C++ Application`. Which is the best configuration for this problem?

I'm using Debian Squeeze, Eclipse CDT and GCC as compiler

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully built your project and have an executable you can run (no build errors, project properly configured as executable), just press a "search project" or "browse" button in "debug configurations" dialog and point it to your executable.

Comment: That's exactly the point when a press the "search project" button it doesn't appear anything and when i browse the project i can't find the binaries, that's what i don't understand

Comment: What does build console print out when you build?

Comment: It says: `Cannot run program "make": Unknown reason`

Comment: That means you have no binary. You probably can run make from command line (try make --version)?

Comment: No, it doesn't work i tried the make from a terminal and it didn't work, is there any possibility that the eclipse configuration could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have GNU make installed? If not, install it. (http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=make)